# How to create hooks like in Wordpress for custom CMS?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, wordpress, express

I was impressed when I found out WordPress hooks such as Actions and Filters, where you can modify or change your whole CMS functionality just from one custom function and its hook. I'm looking for the method or architecture pattern or even code example, which will explain how does it work. What do you have to write to your custom class (for example) to allow you to change some core features? No matter CMS or programming language. It could be WordPress or custom JS/PHP CMS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in many ways, but the basic concept is pretty simple. For this I’ll show you what WordPress does at a high level using these two functions:

```php
apply_filters($name, $value, …$context)
{
    global $filters;
    foreach($filters[$name] ?? [] as $callback) {
        $value = $callback($value, …$context);
    }
    return $value;
}

add_filter($name, $callback)
{
    global $filters;
    if(!isset($filters[$name])){
        $filters[$name] = [];
    }
    $filters[$name][] = $callback;

}
```

The `add_filter` function is where programmers register their interest in changing something. The `$name` parameter is defined by WordPress and is unique to the location it is used in the code (or unique enough as long as multiple callers all do the same thing with the data). The `$callback` parameter is custom code to do something with the data, and return something. Everything in here is stored in a global array.

The `apply_filters` function is where WordPress code loops over the global array for a specific named key which returns a sub array where each element is a callback. It then calls each callback with the specific `$value` of interest, along with any optional `$context` that someone might need.

I’m missing a bunch of sanity checking in here, but that’s the gist. In WordPress’s case, there’s actually a dedicated object for filters that gets stored in the global array, and there’s priorities so programmers can hint at the order that their `$callback` gets registered at.

The usage is very simple in core code then:

```php
// Normal code here
$data = get_data();
// See if anyone wants to change it
$data = apply_filters('after_get_data', $data);
// Back to normal code
```

Actions are similar to filters, and in WordPress’s case, they share the same core logic. The only major difference is that actions don’t return anything, but otherwise share the same pattern of a common `$name` along with some optional arguments.

Another way that WordPress allows extensions is through pluggable code. Basically, there’s a file that’s loaded really late with a bunch of functions wrapped in `if(!function_exists('…')){}`. This allows other programmers to create these functions and WordPress will use the programmers version instead of core’s.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I still don't understand how inner code is written. Where does it put PHP function snippets and how does it run it? As I think, there might be some core class that extended or runs our custom filter callback.

Comment: The “inner code” is literally just doing normal boring PHP stuff, and every once in a while it calls `apply_filters` which is a way of shouting “anyone want to change my data?” This is sprinkled throughout the core code. “I’m about to go to the database with these parameters, anyone want to change them” is the `pre_get_posts` filter for instance, followed by “I just got a bunch of data from the database, anyone want to change it” which is the `get_posts` filter.

Comment: You can see the code for these functions write in the documentation, too. Like I said, I simplified it, but the spirit is the same. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

Comment: Aight, I'll check. Thanks for advice.